# Create definition of 'xxx': Unable to create function 'xxx'. Function signature was copied to clipboard

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a class written in a header file, with a function declaration:

File: Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
    void Update();
}
```

Note that there is no `Foo.cpp` file at this point.

I right click on `Update`, and do the quick action/refactor `Create definition of 'Update' in Foo.cpp` (as described in the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/refactoring/create-declaration-definition?view=msvc-160)).

What is supposed to happen is that `Foo.cpp` is created, with `#include Foo.h` on the first line, and the function definition added.

Instead what happens is `Foo.cpp` is created, **without** `#include Foo.h` on the first line, and the function definition is **not** added. Additionally, I get a pop-up saying "Unable to create function 'Update'. Function signature was copied to clipboard."

Repeatedly trying to create the definition will cause the same error pop-up to re-open.

If I manually go into `Foo.cpp` and add `#include Foo.h` at the top, the create-definition action will now work for `Foo.h`.

I never had this problem a couple of months ago, perhaps it is due to the latest updates of vs-2019, though I cannot verify this. The issue affects both community edition 16.9.1 and 16.9.2. I have submitted a bug report to Microsoft for this.

It's a very tedious issue when creating lots of files/functions, I am looking for a solution or workaround to fix this.

### EDIT

In response to comments, here is an additional test case to reproduce the error:

```
class Foo
{
    void Update();
};
```

Comment: The class definition has a syntax error. Perhaps, this a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get a resolution to this?  I've had the same problem for months (years?) and it's still happening (currently at 16.11.25).

I finally decided to try and do something about it.  I enabled logging in VS (/Log switch) in hopes to see some error info getting logged.  Nope, no help.

Then it dawned on my that maybe this was only happening in new uncommitted header files.  So I did a git commit to include the new header file, then tried `Create definition of 'x' in y.cpp` again, and it worked!

Okay, partial win I guess.

Is this the same situation for you perchance?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `Create definition of'Update' in Foo.cpp` cannot create `Update` function and `Foo.cpp`. So, you could submit this question to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

However, in the case that the Foo.cpp file has been created, `Create definition of'Update' in Foo.cpp` can create `Update` function. Also, I suggest that you could use `Create Declaration/Definition`. It could create `Foo.cpp` and `Update` function without the cpp file.
[image]